# Liquids that show fluorescense for detecting 532 laser

Tags: fluorescence

I have used tonic water and, better, antifreeze, for aligning UV lasers with sample cells in my various setups. I am now working with 532nm and would like a similar readily available substance. I did not find these to fluoresce very well. Olive oil does not work either.
Has anyone found a "household" liquid that lights up well in a borosilicate cell with a 532 laser. Returning a longer wavelength (red-orange) would work nicely especially with protective googles for 532.

thanks
Fritz

Comment: Try dissolving a little turmeric in water or isopropyl alcohol. (I use a laser dye in ethanol because I happen to have the dye.) Red “glow sticks” have dye ampoules that work well.

Comment: @EdV -That should be an answer. But why do you need flourescence to align a visible laser?

Comment: @mmesser314 For low power lasers in the visible spectral range, I generally just use business cards to show where the beam is. But fluorescent solutions, uranium glass, fluorescent plexiglass sheets and pieces, can be useful for visualizing focusing effects, light scatter, etc.

Comment: You needed the really nice business cards to get good UV response. Helped to distinguish the good sales people from the not so good (more sales meant more expensive business cards).

Comment: Ed. Aligning a visible laser is OK if you can see the beam. As it enters a liquid filled cell the beam can be difficult to see. I am trying to focus it to a spot in the center of the cell. Outside the cell I use a piezo vapour generator and it shows the beam quite nicely. (It takes several bounces to and from the cell as this is a multi-pass system.